# Запуск приложений в потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность, процесс

Как можно реализовать запуск списка приложений по очереди в отдельном потоке? Т.е. следующие приложение запускается в отдельном потоке после завершения предыдущего.

Comment: это лишено любого здравого смысла. Потоки существуют для того и только для того, чтобы запускать выполнение задач **параллельно**, а не последовательно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приложения сами по себе имеют отдельный процесс. Для ожидания завершения запущенного приложения есть метод WaitForExit.

Должно получиться что-то такое:

```
new Thread(() => 
{
  foreach(var cmd in cmds)
    Process.Start(cmd).WaitForExit();
}).Start();
```